# Obtener mediante JQuery el valor de un elemento

Tags: jquery

Como puedo obtener el valor que tengo dentro de es input?

```
<p id="1">1 <input value="" type="text"></p>
```

Comment: No recomendaría que usaras un número únicamente para etiquetar el `id` de tus elementos, ni tampoco que el mismo empiece por un número. Antes de HTML 5 esto no era válido, y aunque funcione en HTML, podrías tener problemas en otros contextos, como por ejemplo en CSS y hasta en Javascript según el caso (si intentas usar regex por ejemplo), para más detalles puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/5587982) en SO en inglés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta buscando el elemento con el id `1` que seria el elemento `p` y luego el `input`:

```js
function obtenerValor()
{
  console.log($("#1 input").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="1">1 <input value="" type="text"></p>
<button onclick='obtenerValor()'>Obtener valor</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sí es para un campo tipo de texto o numérico, se haría con `.val()`

Sí lo que quiere es obtener el texto contenido dentro de un elemento **html**, se hace con un `.text()`

Así:

```js
function obtenerValorDeCampo()
{
  console.log($("#campo").val());
}

function obtenerValorDeElemento()
{
  console.log($("#1").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="1">1 <input id="campo" value="" type="text"></p>
<button onclick='obtenerValorDeCampo()'>Obtener valor de campo</button>
<button onclick='obtenerValorDeElemento()'>Obtener valor de elemento</button>
```

Comment: ¿Qué elemento diferente aporta tu respuesta, con respecto a la respuesta de @Einer? En la pregunta queda claro que quiere obtener el valor de un elemento `input`. ¿Qué significa *dentro de un html*? ¿Acaso el  `input` no es un elemento html también?